# Prove that $\forall z \in(0,1)$, $\frac{z+1}{2}>z$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

For some context, the initial problem that I was working on was proving that for the set $A=(0,1)$ we have $\sup(A)=1$. My argument relied on the fact that for $z \in(0,1)$ we have that $$\frac{z+1}{2}>z $$ However, I wanted to prove rigorously that this result is true (it is given without proof in the lecture notes I am reading). Here is my attempt:

First I would like to prove that $\frac{z+1}{2} \in (0,1)$. We know that $z\in(0,1)$, thus $$0<z<1 $$
Which implies that $$0<\frac{z}{2}<\frac{1}{2} $$
Furthermore $$\frac{1}{2}<\frac{z+1}{2}<1$$ Hence it is clear that $\frac{z+1}{2} \in (0,1)$

I now aim to use contradiction to show that $$\frac{z+1}{2}\le z \text{ on } z\in(0,1)$$ is impossible. Cleary equality fails as the only solution is $z=1 \notin (0,1)$, so we are left to show that $\frac{z+1}{2}<z$ is false.
By assumption we have $$0<\frac{z+1}{2}<z $$
We may rearrange this to give $$0<z+1<2z $$
Furthermore $$-1<z<2z-1 $$
Finally $$-1-z<0<z-1 $$
Clearly this gives that $0<z-1$ or in other words, $1<z$ which is equivalent to $z>1$ which can't be as $z\in(0,1)$. The negation of our original statement is false, and so the original statement must be true.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: No need to overcomplicate things. If $z \in (0,1)$, then $z < 1 \Rightarrow 2z < z+1 \Rightarrow z < \frac{z+1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, but there is no need for a contradiction: a direct proof is a single line.

Since $z \in (0,1)$, then $1>z$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{z+1}{2} > \frac{z+z}{2} = z
$$

Comment: You are correct. I suppose it is easy to get lost in the details. Perhaps there is an award for most convoluted proof?

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a few wires crossed since I had to make a similar answer to someone else recently

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach the supremum problem. By definition, the supremum of a given set $A \neq \emptyset$ is the minimum element which is bigger or equal than every element of $A$. In other words, if we consider the sets of upper bounds of $A$, let's denote it $\mathcal U$, then
$$\sup(A) = \min (\mathcal U)$$
Note that it always exists. If $A=(0,1)$, then
$$\mathcal U = [1,+\infty)$$
Therefore.
$$\sup(A) = \min (\mathcal U) = \min \{x\in [1,+\infty)\} = 1$$

Comment: $\mathcal{U}$ may be empty in which case $\min(\mathcal{U})$ is ill-defined. In a general case nonempty $\mathcal{U}$ may also not _have_ a minimal element (for example in $\mathbb{Q}$ for $A = \{q : \: q < \sqrt{2}\}$, $\mathcal{U} = \{q:\: q>\sqrt{2}\}$). The fact that it can't be so in $\mathbb{R}$ requires additional proof.

Comment: @Abstraction, I see what you say that my argument might not work in a nonbounded set; however, every upper bounded set it $\mathbb R$ has a supremum, so for this example, $A=(0,1)$, my argument  is valid :)